# C - File to integer matrix with fread reads only first value

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, fread

I have two files with each one containing the values of a square matrix. 
In my program I want to extract those values and put them in 2d static arrays. I HAVE to use fread (assignment..).Names of the files and size of the matrixes are passed through argv.
However, only the first value of each matrix is read, so the output with printf is :

```
2 2 2  and 4 4 4
2 2 2      4 4 4
2 2 2      4 4 4
```

Here is my code. I suppose I made a stupid and simple mistake, but I don't which one.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){


int i,j;
int res;
int n=atoi(argv[3]);

int tab1[n][n];
int tab2[n][n];

FILE *f1;
f1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(f1==NULL){
    perror("Error f1");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

else {

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            fread(&(tab1[i][j]),sizeof(int),1,f1);
        }

}


FILE *f2;
f2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
if(f2==NULL){
    perror("Error f2");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

else {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            fread(&(tab2[i][j]),sizeof(int),1,f2);
        }
    }
    fclose(f2);


    }
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("%d ",tab1[i][j]);
    printf("\n");

}

printf("\n");
//displaying the matrixes
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("%d ",tab2[i][j]);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: *"... each one containing the values of a square matrix."* - as *text* ? or written as bytes by some other nefarious means ? If the former (likely), then `fread` is not the correct function to use. You need a formatted input ideology if that is the case, such as [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @WhozCraig yes the files are text files. But I have to use fread (homework...)

Comment: The sadist that has you using `fread` for reading formatted input is pure academia evil. Barring severely constricted embedded systems, that's the only place anyone would do that. Regardless, given that restriction you need to read the *characters*, effectively mimicking what `scanf` would do for a `%d` input, and translate them into their native types (`int` in this case). It would actually be *easier* if you could just use `fgetc`, but I suppose that's off the table too. If your homework assignment isn't titled "How to turn 10 lines of code into 150", it certainly should be.

Comment: Sadist is accurate...And the guidelines are to use fread only to read files, so no fgetc either. What would be the file types that can be used with fread?

Comment: Is this for an embedded C class ? That would be the only *legitimate* reason anyone would have such a restriction. Regardless, there are no native type associations using `fread` outside of the basic octet (bytes), as signed or unsigned char. That's why reading/writing raw data from implementation types is so non-portable (lookup endianness on Google). There is a LOT of work involved if you need to do all these translations yourself. And `fread` is about as inefficient as they come (second only to completely unbuffered system call `read`). Ironic he lets you use `atoi`, btw, but not `fgetc`.

Comment: There is also the possibility that I'm just misunderstanding the assignment and rather, he wants you to `fread` the entire file into a big arse memory buffer, then walk through it using `atoi` on each cell, translating to `int` and storing in your target matrix.

Comment: My class is about system programation, and C is the language we learn and use for this class. He didn't say anything about the string functions, the question just said "you have to read and write files with fread and fwrite". But I didn't think about the buffer option. Would this buffer be a static array or a dynamic array?

Comment: Dynamic, based on the file size (calculated via fseek, ftell, etc.). You could use a fixed buffer, just reading  and repopulating it as the buffer is exhausted whilst you're consuming digits, but that can get complicated, particularly when that boundary falls in the middle of a value string. Regardless, the one thing you seemed to not know until now is that `fread` cares about reading raw data, not about types beyond `char/unsigned char`. If you want more, you have to do it with higher level functions or put in the work to use what you're limited to. Bummer, I know, but reality nonetheless.

Comment: Okay...Well I will try to find a solution with that. I wish I was told all this information about fread...Thanks for your help nonetheless.